Can Muon Catalyzed Fusion work in a Plasma?
From what I understand, muon catalyzed fusion works by injecting muons into the deuterium and tritium, which then they replace the electron shared between the hydrogen isotopes in a molecule, making the orbit of the shared particle around 200x closer to the nuclei, which makes the nuclei much closer together, increasing their chances of fusion. I've never heard of any temperature limits of muon catalyzed fusion, so I am wondering on whether it could work in a plasma. But from what I understand, there aren't any molecules in plasma, so would it still work?

Short answer: It (most probably) does not enhance the fusion rate in the sense that the needed plasma temperature is reduced.
Detailed answer: As you correctly described the expected catalyzing effect of muons originates from the reduced Bohr radius when exchanging the bound electron with a muon in a Hydrogen or Deuterium molecule (H2, D2). The repulsive potential of the two bound ions is shielded by the muon on such a small length scale that the ions can come very close to each other so that even at room temperatures DD fusion could take place.
Now, in a plasma all charge carriers are freely moving and no bound states exist. Consequently, the electric potential of a ion is screened not by one but by many particles. The relevant length scale for this screening (reduction of potential to 1/e) is called the Debye length ($\lambda_D$) and defined as:
$$\lambda_D = \sqrt{\epsilon_0kT/ne^2} $$
It can be seen that the screening length scale only depends on the temperature (T), density (n) and the electric charge. There is no dependency on the mass as is the case in bound states through the Bohr radius. Thereby, exchanging electrons with muons does not change the Debye length and thereby does not have a catalyzing effect on the fusion cross section.
Moreover, it is interesting to note that in low density, high temperature plasmas (which are created in modern thermonuclear fusion experiments) the Debye shielding has nearly no effect on the fusion cross section. Assuming a density of 1e20m$^{-3}$ and a temperature of 1keV the Debye length is around 2e-5m while the distance of closest approach between two ions is around 1e-12m. Consequently, Debye shielding is irrelevant at these plasma parameters. In very high density plasmas (e.g. stars) the situation can be a lot different.

You mentioned that in very high density plasmas, it can be a lot different. How would it still work in a highly dense plasma if there are no molecules.

That sentence was referring to the Debye shielding relevance on the fusion cross section. Naively looking at the formula for the Debye length nothing changes when exchanging electrons with muons (assuming T and n stay constant). So in your words it wouldn't "work".


I've never heard of any temperature limits of muon catalyzed fusion,
so I am wondering on whether it could work in a plasma. But from what
I understand, there aren't any molecules in plasma, so would it still
work?

Yes, for one definition of "work", but it would be self-defeating.
The "yes" is that sure, a muon in a plasma will work just as well as a muon in liquid D-T. If it hits an atom, it may replace the electron... etc.
But...
The energy needed to create a muon is much higher than the energy released by a catalyzed fusion reaction. For it to "work", the muon has to be released from the reactants and go on to join another atom. To be energy-positive it has to catalyze something on the order of 500 fusions. No one has come up with a way to do this.
... and that is going to be really difficult to arrange in a plasma. The geometry is working against you. You need to make sure it sees 500 ions before decaying in 2.2 usec, and by increasing the distance between the ions you're stretching out that time and making matters worse. So, yeah, the catalyzed reaction can still occur, but in a plasma, it is going to reduce the net energy.
That assumes we are talking about the plasma in a tokamak or similar. In the case of ICF where the density is on the order of 100 times that of lead, things change. In this case, I suspect that the mean free path of the reaction is greater than the size of the compressed fuel, but I can't say for sure.

My question is how would it work in plasma. If a plasma has no molecules, how can Muon Catalyzed Fusion work?
